# Facebook graph API conversations webhook is not responding

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, fbsdk, react-native-fbsdk

I have set up a webhook callback here(https://glitch.com/edit/#!/nego-graph-api-webhook) and I also subscribe to `conversations` field on webhook page. 
[image]

also, I have tested it with the Test button, I can see the response in my console. However, when I send a new message to my page, the webhook is not called?

May I know which part I'm missing out?

Comment: You did not subscribe your app for updates from the specific page.

Comment: As @CBroe pointed out, the page will need to install the app. This is a POST request to `/{page_id}/subscribed_apps` using the page access token https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/subscribed_apps#Creating

Comment: @CBroe thanks for the reply, i got it working now :)

Comment: @Bangdel thanks for the reply, i got it working now :) however, may I know is there a way to get the message text? because currently the webhook return thread_id, thread_key and page_id. Is the away to get just the content of the msg instead? or i'm required to make another api call to get that?

Comment: @JohnLim If the content that you are looking for is not in the payload, then it probably means you need to make another call. The payload of the Webhook is rather static and you cannot choose to add/omit items from it.